# How can I delete a file from FTP with FTPWebRequest

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp

```
Dim FTPRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(FTPServer & "something.txt"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
FTPRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(FTPUsername, FTPPassword)
FTPRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile
```

I want to delete file via this method from ftp but the file not deleted and not giving any errors 
Sorry for my English
Thanks
when ı try this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does never run the request, it only creates the object.

You can run the request as follows:

```
Dim response As FtpWebResponse = CType(FTPRequest.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
```

Get the result from `StatusDescription` property.

```
MsgBox(response.StatusDescription) 'show status
```

Also have a look at the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebresponse.statusdescription?view=netframework-4.8